# Как проверить присутствует ли в переменной определенное значение?

Tags: php

Всем привет, есть задача проверить присутствует ли в переменной `$name` допусти `history`, можно было бы сделать обычным сравнением, но дело в том что `$name` равняется значением ячейки в БД `$row['cell']`, а в ячейке хранятся не одно слово, а набор (вот `history mathematics physics biology`)

Пробовал через `in_array`  но подходит тлько для массива

Какие еще есть функции или каким способом лучше всего определить?

Comment: а вы строку в массив разберите explode()

Comment: @Mike думал об этом, но ничего дельного не нашел, сейчас попробую, спасибо

Comment: @Mike проверил, все работает, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил просто перевести строку в массив, точно не знал как, @Mike подсказал что нужно через  explode()

```
    $name = $row['cell'];(history mathematics physics biology)                                  
    $pieces = explode(" ", $name);

    if (in_array("history",$pieces)){ 
        $xxx = "История"; 
    }
    if(in_array("physics",$pieces)){ 
        $zzz = "Физика"; 
    }
```

Comment: если эксплодить через пробел, то запятые будут "не в теме" (как и другие разделители)

Answer (score 1):

```
$name= 'history,mathematics,physics,biology';
$find= 'history';
$pos      = strripos($name, $find);
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "erorr";
} else {
    echo "Вхождение ($find) нашел в ($name) в позиции ($pos)";
}
```

Comment: А теперь определите, есть ли в строке "history,mathematics,physics,neurobiology" слово "biology". ваш текущий код даст совпадение  ...

Comment: @Mike Согласен) но можно проверить на запятую $pos-1 и следующую, которая встретится (но это костыль). Ваш вариант, естественно, больше подходит

Comment: Ну тогда регуляркой - не-символ+поиск+несимвол

Answer (score 1):

**strpos()** — Возвращает позицию первого вхождения подстроки

```
if( strpos($name,'history') ){
    // нашли history и чевойта делаем...
}
```

**strstr()** — Находит первое вхождение подстроки (регистрозависима)
**stristr()** — Находит первое вхождение подстроки (регистронезависима)

```
if (strstr($name, 'history')){
    // нашли history и чевойта делаем...
}
```

**preg_match()** - Выполняет проверку на соответствие регулярному выражению

```
if (preg_match("/history/i", $name)){
    // нашли history и чевойта делаем...
}
```

Всё из [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.strings.php)